# How many Views should a single Activity show?

Tags: android, android-view

I know that in XML, Views are expensive, and ideally you should strive for as little as possible. But in my case, I am designing my layout in a such a way that I am sort of forced to have a lot of Views, close to 80. Eclipse gave me a warning on this, so I deleted some Views, but I can only do so much as my implementation requires minimum, 48 Views off the bat, and not including some extra stuff. So my question is in whether I should really find a simpler way, or if its fine. What is the actual number that really should be maximum?

**XML file**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/top_bar_date_display"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="July 1, 2012"
        android:background="#696969"/>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/day_view_floaty_holder"
    android:background="#000000">
    <GridLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="1" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="12\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="1\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="2\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="3\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="4\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="5\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="6\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="7\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="8\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="9\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="10\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="11\nAM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="12\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="1\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="2\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="3\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="4\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="5\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="6\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="7\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="8\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="9\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="10\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="11\nPM"
                android:background="#bebebe"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>

    <!-- THIS GRIDLAYOUT IS WHERE THE EVENTS WILL BE PLACED-->
    <GridLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="1" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_4"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_6"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_7"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_8"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_9"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_10"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_11"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_12"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_13"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_14"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_15"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_16"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_17"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_18"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_19"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_20"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_21"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_22"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/day_view_23"
            android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

I should probably explain the logic behind what the code translated to. I essentially needed a GridLayout of 24 rows, as well as another GridLayout of another 24 rows floated above it. I did this to separate what I need to float above the first GridLayout. Its suppose to be for a Day View for a calendar app.

Comment: Would you be able to provide us with example of your xml file, maybe we can figure out a way to trim this number down?

Comment: Its long, but I shall provide :)

Comment: For the record, if anyone wonders why I am not using ListView or GridView with an Adapter, there are limitations with what I am trying to do. Believe me I reallllly wanted to avoid adding all this xml, but right now this is the best I could come up with. Just for extra info, its suppose to be a day view for a calendar.

Comment: I thought that creating your views in XML allowed the android parser to pre-compile them, making it more efficient.

Comment: Really @Kickaha ? I assumed this, but eclipse gave me a warning. It only said that I should avoid 80+ Views as it is an efficiency thing. But of course, maybe its only giving me advice. I just don't want to overkill the users memory.

Comment: Those `LinearLayout` wrapping a `TextView` groups scream for a `ListView`(this is the layout from the previous question's image?). What are the limitations that prevent you from using one? Also I think you could do just fine without those `LinearLayouts` and simply use the `TextViews`.

Comment: Hello again @Luksprog Well, if I were to use ListView, then I would need to figure out a way to float the Views over the `dividers` for one. I cannot have the Dividers disappear when a View needs to take 2 items, to simulate a bigger event (since its a day view layout for a calendar). I cannot do this using ListView or GridView. The way I figured out how to fix it was to float a GridLayout above a ListView, but its frowned upon to put a scrolling View inside of another scrolling View, but if I don't do this, the GridLayout floating will be statically placed on the screen.

Comment: Oh, and yes, you both are correct @Kickaha I actually completely agree with you. The reason I am forced to do it is because the way I tried to limit the amount of Views was by leaving only a `TextView` and then I am set. Only thing is I need some sort of divider in between each item in the List. Normally in GridView I would just do `android:horizontalSpacing`, and have whatever background the parent of it has another color from what the GridView has, to sort of simulate a divider (does that make sense). That way I save Views. It would have worked perfectly otherwise, and saved me 24 Views!

Comment: I think I understand what you want but that is not the way to do it. Can you share more details about the data for a day? How is the user inserting events in the day(if it is by clicking on an entry in the layout above, how he/she can combine two or more hours(can he combine more than two rows?)?). do you expect to have only a `TextView` in one row(what about if the user combines two rows)?

Comment: @Luksprog it works like a regular calendar insertion. User inputs some info: event name, time, location, etc. in a separate Activity and then whatever day is chosen, those are the events shown in the day view. I would be very grateful if you could give me a much better way of doing this! But I would only really show the event name and time. Not too much to show. Let me know if you need a better clarification. As for how 2 or more hours are combined, it just exists. I am getting it from the database, so it would all be ready to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said I would use a `ListView` to show the data to avoid making so much views. First I would create a class to represent the user events that you show in the list:

```
private static class Event {

        public int startHour;
        public int hours = 1;
        public String name;
        public String date;
        public boolean isEmptyEvent = true;

        public Event(int startHour, int hours, String name, String date,
                boolean isEmptyEvent) {
            this.startHour = startHour; 0 to 23 (the method getStartHour makes this pretty)
            this.hours = hours; // how many this event requires(default 1)
            this.name = name;
            this.date = date;
            this.isEmptyEvent = isEmptyEvent;
        }

        public String getStartHour() {
            // should optimize this method so you don't end up creating String
            // after String(char array?)!
            if (startHour < 10) {
                return "0" + startHour + ":00";
            }
            return String.valueOf(startHour) + ":00";
        }
    }
```

Then I would parse the data I have in `Events` object(I don't know what you save in the database so this is just guessing):

```
public SparseArray<Event> getData(String date) {
        // here you get the data from the database and create Events object for
        // those dates
        SparseArray<Event> data = new SparseArray<Event>(); // for efficiency
                // add some random events
        data.put(3, new Event(3, 1, "Breackfast", date, false));// one event at 3 taking 1 hour
        data.put(14, new Event(14, 3, "Lunch", date, false));// one event at 14 taking 3 hour
        data.put(20, new Event(20, 2, "Dinner", date, false));// one event at 20 taking 2 hour
        return data;
    }
```

Then in the adapter I would fill the rest of the empty entries(where the user didn't yet set anything) with empty `Events` objects and show it to the user. As the code is a little big I will not post it here , instead you can find the full activity+ layouts here https://gist.github.com/3370107

Comment: How did you solve the issue with the dividers in between the items in the ListView, or putting it another way, the effect of a View in an item appearing to float to the next item with the divider still present? I want it to still be there, even when an item extends past a single hour/item. I was actually going to do it like you just did, but then that dividers issue came up.

Comment: @Andy I simply removed the dividers. From my point of view showing inner dividers doesn't make sense, the event should visually occupy uninterrupted all the hours rows it needs. I've made a modification in the `getView` method from the gist I posted, to simulate the dividers visually. If you try to also add other data for the rows that are unoccupied in an event then my code will not work.

Comment: After really thinking about it, I think I will just do it the way I originally thought, a.k.a what you are telling me to do. It really is the best approach. Much more energy efficient. I really appreciate the time you took showing me example code on gist. I do ask one thing, how many Views maximum should be shown in the window though?

Comment: @Andy I don't recall of a fix number, 80 seems to be recommended limit. The real issue isn't the number, what should you aim is to have fewer `Views` as possible. Each one, stresses the CPU, occupies memory and this is happening on a resource limited device(not to mention the time it takes to measure and draw a huge layout three(and a deep one to), you could check the `hierarchyviewer` toolto see this in action).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your xml document, you could solve this very easily with a ListView and ListAdapter.

You could shrink that xml document to one main xml file containing the 'top_bar_date_display' TextView and a ListView. Secondly you would have a xml layout file which contained a list row item. The ListAdapter would then set the details of the row. You then implement a list adapter which contains an array of custom objects representing each row you require. The list adapter sets the text in the getView method based on which position in the array.

The list row could look like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rowItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bebebe"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="[Replaced by ListAdapter]"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/event1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Edit:

If the listview has no divider, we make the children of the row view styled so they create a fake divider, then the list adapter can then set the width of 'event1' for row 1 and use the same width for 'event1' in row 2. As 'event1' is between two rows, you would choose that 'event1' in row1 shows no (fake) divider and because they have the same background it will appear as if they are one object, you'll have to do some silly stuff for pressed states etc though.

The ListAdapter can also dynamically create new events to be added with rowItem.addView(new LinearLayout). Just have to keep track of all events, the rows they span and any collisions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I mention above that I need to implement it the way I am doing because `ListView` and `GridView` paired with an `Adapter` has its limitation for a day view layout for a calendar. I wouldn't be able to simulate, say a View stretching to two items in the List correctly, at least without the divider disappearing, but I need it there. If you can think of a way to float Views into two item places in a ListView without making the ListView's divider null, that'd be great! Then my problem would be solved! But in either case, my question really is more about the # of Views